# What time of the year should I e-mail professors to enquire about PhD positions in France?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, email, deadlines, france

Edit: My question is not a duplicate of following question:[How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x) because in answer to this question nobody has answered about the system in France.

I completed my master's in mathematics in  June 2020 but couldn't apply in session 2021 due to personal reasons for a PhD in France.

Now, I am studying some topics and this year is my last chance for getting admission for a PhD.

Before what month must I send my CV and e-mail to the professors whom I want to work with so that I can get selected for session 2022?

I would have started sending them by now, but I didn't because I have been busy in doing some old pending work.

I can't miss this chance.

Kindly guide.

Comment: To anyone answering this question: please also update [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/177050/68109), if applicable.

Comment: You didn't mention the countries. I suggest, however, that you make contact immediately.

Comment: @Buffy See 2nd line of my question.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. But get the mail moving.

Comment: You've already asked a very similar question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/173104/135841). The answer you accepted contains (in the first paragraph, actually) the information that there don't exist  "sessions" or "hiring seasons" for most PhD positions in Germany. By corollary, there is no universal deadline, but everything depends on the individual position. I'm not sure why you ask a question that has already been answered to you.

Comment: (Apart from that, some (all?) of the DAAD scholarships which I mentioned in a comment under your related question probably *do* have application deadlines. Details about those can be found on the DAAD webpage.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck I am also asking about france here.

Comment: @YannicMuller: Yes, sure (since you haven't received a reply about France to the other question). My point was that you already know the answer for Germany, so it would make sense to remove Germany from the current question.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Ok! doing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x)

Comment: @HermanToothrot There is no answer for France yet in that question, please see [this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/68109) related discussion.

Comment: @HermanToothrot There is no discussion on France in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as possible.

Most of the positions (financed via the graduate schools) have already been filled, but some advisors who have independent financing (such as ANR grants) might still be looking for candidates to start, say, January 1st.

If unsuccessful, you could re-apply next year. Most PhD students start their contract on October 1st, and the selection process takes place in spring and summer.

Best of luck!